# SQL Expressions in Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, editor, expression

I am not at all familiar with SQL expressions and was hoping to get some help
I have this:
"Reservations"."NY IT Services/Computer Presentation"
which is a boolean

How would i write this to say "If 
"Reservations"."NY IT Services/Computer Presentation" is a 1, then display, else do not display?

I need to do this in Crystal Reports and create a custom field to help me filter through information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a suppress formula on whatever field you want to conditionally display. The formula must result in a boolean. Crystal will convert a bit field to it's own boolvar type, so the formula would look something like this...

`Not {table.some_bit_column}`